# Power Query: some values are counted from zero when count should start at a higher value

Tags: merge, count, powerbi, increment, powerquery

I have a column with values counting occurrences.

I am trying to continue the series in Power Query.

I am thus trying to increment 1 to the max of the given column..

The ID column has rows with letter tags : AB or BE. Following these letters, specific numeric ranges are associated. For both AB and BE, number ranges first from 0000 to 3000 and from 3000 to 6000.

I thus have the following possibilities: From AB0000 to AB3000 From AB3001 to AB6000 From BE0000 to BE3000 From BE3001 to AB6000

Each category match to the a specific item in my column geography, from the other workbook: From AB0000 to AB3000, it is ItalyZ From AB3001 to AB6000, it is ItalyB From BE0000 to BE3000, it is UKY From BE3001 to AB6000, it is UKM

I am thus trying to find the highest number associated to the first AB category, the second AB category, the first BE category, and the second.

My issue is that for some values, there is simply "*nothing*" yet in we source file.

This means that there is no occurrence yet of UKM for example.

Here is an example with no UKM or UKY:

```
  |------------------|---------------------|    
  |       Max        |      Geography      |
  |------------------|---------------------|
  |      0562        |        ItalyZ       |
  |------------------|---------------------|
  |     0563         |        ItalyZ       |
  |------------------|---------------------|
```

Hence, I have the following result:

```
  |------------------|---------------------|    
  |    Increment     |          Place      |
  |------------------|---------------------|
  |      0564        |        ItalyZ       |
  |------------------|---------------------|
  |     0565         |        ItalyZ       |
  |------------------|---------------------|
  |     0565         |        ItalyZ       |
  |------------------|---------------------|
  |     null         |        UKM          |
  |------------------|---------------------|
```

Here is the used power query code:

```
    let
    Source = #table({"Prefix", "Seq_Start", "Seq_End","GeoLocation"},{{"AB",0,2999,"ItalyZ"},{"AB",3000,6000,"ItalyB"},{"BC",0,299,"UKY"},{"BC",3000,6000,"UKM"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Seq_Start", Int64.Type}, {"Seq_End", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Prefix"}, HighestID, {"Prefix"}, "HighestID", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded HighestID" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "HighestID", {"Number"}, {"Number"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded HighestID", each [Number] >= [Seq_Start] and [Number] <= [Seq_End]),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Prefix", "Seq_Start", "Seq_End", "GeoLocation"}, {{"NextSeq", each List.Max([Number]) + 1, type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

I would like to know how I could insure that when I have the first occurrence of a value, I would not have "null", but "0000" (or 0) and so on for the next occurrences.

Because, for example, if I have 0 occurrences of UKY before, I do not know why but the end results will be as follows:

```
  |------------------|---------------------|    
  |    Increment     |          Place      |
  |------------------|---------------------|
  |         1        |        UKM          |
  |------------------|---------------------|
  |         2        |        UKM          |
  |------------------|---------------------|
```

Which is not ideal because UKM should start at 30000. And because I had no values recorded before, it is starting with "*null*" only and then, 1, 2...rather than 3001 and 3002.

Comment: This seemed to me to be confusing.  Could you just post a sample of two or three tables, what the output looks like, and what you want the output to look like instead

Comment: Yes. I actually found a solution, but I found it far from elegant. I indicated that "null" (if "null" is found) should be treated as a bigining a series.